# Extracting Bits and Shifting

Tags: c, casting, bitwise-operators

I don't understand why the following code output is 0xffffffef,... instead of 0xef. Kindly help me understand this:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
main()
{
    int i;
    int n = 4;
    char txBuff = 0;
    long Data_b = 0xABCDEF;
    int y = sizeof(txBuff);
    printf("%d\n",y);

    txBuff = (Data_b & 0xff);
    for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        txBuff = (Data_b & 0xff);
        //  txBuff= txBuff & 0xff;
        Data_b = (Data_b >> 8);
        printf("txBuff[%d]=%x, Data_b=%x \n", i, txBuff, Data_b);
    }
}
```

output:

```
1
txBuff[0]=ffffffef, Data_b=abcd 
txBuff[1]=ffffffcd, Data_b=ab 
txBuff[2]=ffffffab, Data_b=0 
txBuff[3]=0, Data_b=0
```

Comment: Try `unsigned char txBuff = 0;` And of course take care about the other problem shown in existing answer.

Answer (score 1):

You're printing with the wrong placeholders:

```
printf("txBuff[%d]=%hhx, Data_b=%lx \n",i,txBuff,Data_b);
```

When you interpret an argument incorrectly you're going to see all kinds of *weird* results.

Here `%hhx` means "hex dumped `unsigned char`" and `%lx` means "hex dumped `unsigned long`" as per the [`printf` notation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf).

For what it's worth `clang` helpfully complains:

```
tbuff.c:17:60: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'long' [-Wformat]
             printf("txBuff[%d]=%x, Data_b=%x \n",i,txBuff,Data_b);
                                           ~~              ^~~~~~
                                           %lx
```

Comment: You are right about that type mismatch, but at the same timy this answer does not address the problem. At least the question asks about the long hex numbers. This is because `txBuff` is of type `char` and contains a negative value which is sign-extended during conversion to `int`.

Comment: Re “Here `%hhx` means "hex dumped `char`" and `%lx` means "hex dumped `long`"”: That is not what the reference you link to says. It says `%hhx` is for `unsigned char` and `%lx` is for `unsigned long`. And, as Gerhardh indicates, the conversion specifier that Clang complains about is not the one causing the problem for OP.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

Use unsigned types when doing bit operations!

in

```
    char txBuff = 0;
        ...
        txBuff = (Data_b & 0xff);
```

the `txBuff` can become negative and will be propagated to `int` in the `printf()` call.

Comment: Yeah, got it. Thank you